# Ukulele - tuning the C string

Tags: tuning, ukulele

I just bought an inexpensive Ukulele — the model is Aklot Concert Ukulele — I bought one for my niece as it sounded so good.

I am having a problem with tuning. When I try to tune the C string, the tuner goes from B to D and does not even show C. Why is this happening?

Is Aklot a good beginner brand?

Comment: It's probably the tuner causing an issue and not the instrument.  What tuner are you using?  You might be using a guitar tuner that only shows the notes for guitar standard tuning (EADGBe).

Comment: We need to know exactly which tuner you are using, before proffering a sensible answer. It will be the tuner with the problem, not the uke.

Comment: See some of the comments on https://music.stackexchange.com/q/132471/78419

Comment: Are you using the [Aklot clip-on tuner that comes with the ukulele](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b4ZqPiVDhEY&t=143s) if you bought [the starter kit](https://www.aklot.com/goods-47.html)?  See [how to tune another ukulele using a similar clip-on tuner](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8HxHroYse2o).

Comment: Try and find a manual for your tuner. like Edward said it is probably set to guitar but it may have other modes you can switch to. Either a chromatic mode or a ukelele mode in C will work.

Comment: I’d like to add that if these comments have not given you a satisfactory answer to your question then you should edit it and post specific information on your tuner, the brand, model and perhaps a photo.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the tuner. As was mentioned in the comments, first see if your tuner will tune any notes other than EADGBE; if not, then it's a guitar tuner and won't tune a ukulele; get a chromatic tuner. You could also try to count 4 frets towards the bridge on the C string and tune to an E.

You can also try clipping the tuner to different places on the peghead; sometimes, overtones can overwhelm a tuner.